# Load a drawing in Microsoft Visio and show the proper window to the user

Tags: object-oriented, vba

In this scenario, I have VBA code and use Late binding and no error
handling for simplification. Also, my question is not explicitly related to Visio, it could be any else application. Let's just accept that the steps are required and my question really belongs naming and architecture.

### Goal of the code

Load a drawing in Microsoft Visio using VBA and show the proper window to the user.

### Steps

- Attach to running Visio instance (`GetObject`). Or, if none exists, start a new Visio instance (`CreateObject`).
- Bring Visio instance to front. This is necessary, to avoid Visio blinking in the taskbar after loading a visio file
- Load Visio file
- Prevent Visio screen updating to avoid screen flickering caused by my following code
- Sync some data. Whatever will be done with the drawing, doesn't really matter here
- Determine desired Visio window. Loading a Visio file could cause multiple windows of that drawing being opened at once, but there is one specific I want to show
- Activate desired Visio window
- Maximize desired Visio window. An attached Visio instance could be in non-maximized window mode, but I want maximized
- Resume Visio screen updating

### Questions

1. How would you name the 'main' procedure, in my example `OpenVisioDrawing`? As you can see, there also is a helper procedure named `LoadVisioDrawing`, which conflicts a bit with `OpenVisioDrawing`. But naming `OpenVisioDrawing` more complicated like `AssureVisioInstanceLoadDrawingAndShowItToTheUser` isn't really nice.

   This naming problem seems to happen more often to me, when finding short pregnant names for 'assembly procedures' (procedures which do many steps).
2. Or would you solve this naming problem by refactoring my approach?
3. Would you suggest a different architecture at all, considering application instantiating, screen updating, loading, syncing, activating, viewing?

Module `TestVisioInterface`

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    With New VisioInterface
        .OpenVisioDrawing "C:\myVisioFile.vsd", "Custom drawing title"
    End With
End Sub
```

Class `VisioInterface`

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const VISIO_CLASS_ID As String = "Visio.Application"

Public Sub OpenVisioDrawing(ByVal filename As String, someData As String)
    Dim app As Object
    Set app = GetVisioInstance()

    ActivateVisioInstance app

    Dim drawing As Object
    Set drawing = LoadVisioDrawing(app, filename)

    VisioScreenUpdating app, False

    SyncVisioDrawing drawing, someData

    Dim window As Object
    Set window = DetermineDesiredVisioWindow(app, drawing)

    ActivateVisioWindow window

    MaximizeVisioWindow window

    VisioScreenUpdating app, True
End Sub

Private Function GetVisioInstance() As Object
    If VisioInstanceExist() Then
        Set GetVisioInstance = AttachVisioInstance()
    Else
        Set GetVisioInstance = StartVisioInstance()
    End If
End Function

Private Function VisioInstanceExist() As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim visioApp As Object
    Set visioApp = GetObject(, VISIO_CLASS_ID)
    VisioInstanceExist = Not visioApp Is Nothing
End Function

Private Function AttachVisioInstance() As Object
    Set AttachVisioInstance = GetObject(, VISIO_CLASS_ID)
End Function

Private Function StartVisioInstance() As Object
    Set StartVisioInstance = CreateObject(VISIO_CLASS_ID)
End Function

Private Sub ActivateVisioInstance(ByRef app As Object)
    AppActivate app.window.Caption
End Sub

Private Function LoadVisioDrawing(ByRef app As Object, ByVal filename As String) As Object
    Const visOpenRW = &H20
    Set LoadVisioDrawing = app.Documents.OpenEx(filename, visOpenRW)
End Function

Private Sub SyncVisioDrawing(ByRef drawing As Object, ByVal someData As String)
    drawing.Title = someData
End Sub

Private Function DetermineDesiredVisioWindow(ByRef app As Object, ByRef drawing As Object) As Object
    Dim window As Object
    For Each window In app.Windows
        If window.Document Is drawing Then
            Set DetermineDesiredVisioWindow = window
            If window.Caption Like "*:2 *" Then
                Set DetermineDesiredVisioWindow = window
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function

Private Sub ActivateVisioWindow(ByRef window As Object)
    window.Activate
End Sub

Private Sub MaximizeVisioWindow(ByRef window As Object)
    Const visWSMaximized = &H40000000
    window.WindowState = visWSMaximized
End Sub

Private Sub VisioScreenUpdating(ByRef app As Object, ByVal allow As Boolean)
    app.ScreenUpdating = allow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! See [reviewing "design"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1924/23788) on meta. Bottom line: *the code **is** the design*. If the implementation has flaws, they'll be addressed; if the flaws are in the design, that'll be addressed too! But design-only questions that could be better served with diagrams than code (i.e. where code is mere placeholders serving illustrative purposes), are off-topic here. Not sure about [softwareengineering.se]'s scope, feel free to ask on their meta.

Answer (score 2):

### Naming

Although the **VisioInterface** does interface with Visio, it is not an Interface.    It you add more functionality to the class I would name it **VisioDocument**

I agree with @Raystafarian when it comes to the naming of your procedures.  Everything in this class is related to Visio.  Adding Visio to the names of all the procedures is just clutter.

I agree with @Raystafarian when it comes to the naming of `visWSMaximized` and `visOpenRW`.  These values may have constant values but they are actually Enumerations.  Consider adding the Enumerations to the head of the class.  Make them Public if you are going to use them in a parameter of Public Procedure, otherwise make them Private.

```
' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342166(v=office.12).aspx
Public Enum VisWindowStates
    visWSActive = &H4000000
    visWSMaximized = &H40000000
    visWSMinimized = &H20000000
End Enum
```

### Program Flow

The class is somewhat clunky.  It needs some **Public Fields** to bring it together.  **Document** and maybe even **Windows** field will make all the procedure gel better.  For example, you have both **Load** and **Open** procedure but **Activate** uses **AppActivate** to activate the **Window** instead of directly referencing it.

There is no clear starting point to using the class.  Consider writing some sort **Initiate** or **Init** procedure.  I would replace **LoadVisioDrawing** with `Init(Path as String)`.

You should consider using `GetObject(PATH)` to set a direct reference to the file if it already open.  For example: `Set Document = GetObject("C:\myVisioFile.vsd")` will either set a reference the **myVisioFile** file or throw an error.

### Don't Reinvent the Wheel - Model Your Code After Existing Patterns

I try to model my classes after the Applications, Objects, and procedures that they are Interfacing with or mimicking.  Consider **ScreenUpdating**, in both Excel and Visio **ScreenUpdating** is a property that takes an Enumeration.  When I were to write a **ScreenUpdating** procedure in a class module, guess what, I write it as a property that takes an Enumeration.

Does Visio load a Document or does it Open a Document?  It opens one of course.  Anyone familiar with any of the Microsoft Application Models knows this.  If they see `OpenDocument` they instantly know what the procedure is expected to do.  On the other hand when I seen **LoadVisioDrawing**, I had to discern the meaning of both "Load" and "Drawing".  Because I have never used Visio and don't have access to it, I had to research **VSD** to determine that it was a Visio Document format.  It might be advantageous use the more generic name Document.

Modeling your code after existing patterns will make your code more understandable to others and easier to re-assimilate if you have to modify it down the road.  Familiarity makes understanding and learning far easier tasks.

### VisioDocument - VisioInterface Refactored

What follows is rough draft of how I would write the class.  I could not test it because I don't have Visio installed but I am confident that it would not be hard to get it up and running.

```
Option Explicit
Public Enum VisWindowStates
    visWSActive = &H4000000
    visWSMaximized = &H40000000
    visWSMinimized = &H20000000
End Enum

Public mVisioApp As Object
Public mDocument As Object
Public mWindow As Object
Private mScreenUpdating As Boolean
Private mWindowState As XlWindowState
Private mPath As String

Public Function Init(Optional PATH As String) As Boolean
    Const VISIO_CLASS_ID As String = "Visio.Application"
    Dim doc As Object
    mPath = PATH
    If Len(mPath) <> 0 Then
        If Len(Dir(mPath)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "File Not Found"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set mDocument = GetObject(mPath)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If mDocument Is Nothing Then
        Set mVisioApp = CreateObject(VISIO_CLASS_ID)
        If Len(mPath) <> 0 Then
            Set mDocument = mVisioApp.mDocuments.Open(mPath)
        Else
            Set mDocument = mVisioApp.mDocuments.Add
        End If
    Else
        Set mVisioApp = mDocument.Application
    End If
    Init = True
End Function

Public Property Get ScreenUpdating() As Boolean
    ScreenUpdating = mScreenUpdating
End Property

Public Property Let ScreenUpdating(ByVal ScreenUpdating As Boolean)
    mScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdating
End Property

Public Property Get WindowState() As Variant
    WindowState = mWindow.WindowState
End Property

Public Property Let WindowState(ByVal WindowState As VisWindowStates)
    mWindow.WindowState = WindowState
End Property

Public Sub setWindow()
    Set mWindow = mVisioApp.Windows(mDocument.Title)
End Sub
```

### Change Log

- VisWindowStates added to support refactoring of the `WindowState` property
- Init modified to add a new Document when there is no Path specified

Comment: Naming: I completely agree to your suggestions. The hint regarding `VisioDocument` brings a new aspect to the scenario.

Program Flow: "...but Activate uses AppActivate to activate the Window instead of directly referencing it."
`ActivateVisioInstance` activates the Visio Application. `ActivateVisioWindow` activates the window inside Visio.
Maybe you missed this?

All your other remarks and samples I find purposeful. Thanks!

Comment: What does `AppActivate` tell you about the `WindowState` of the document window?  I am assuming that you want to maximize the Window when you activate it.  Why uses two different approaches when you can both `Activate` and `Maximize` the Document by referencing it's Window?  Of course, you would know better about the specifics of your project.  On a side note, I was disappointed to that I could not find a `Document.Window` method in the [MSDN Documentation: Visio Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/document-object-visio).

Comment: I only activate the Visio application **before** opening a drawing to prevent the taskbar blinking.
Then I open the document and take a look, which of the (client) windows belonging to the document is the one I want, and activate and maximize it.
Regarding `Document.Window `: If, at all it would be `Document.Windows`, because a document can have multiple windows. But you're right, it's missing.

Comment: Nice `Init` - really.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple naming observations

> ```
> Private Function VisioInstanceExist() As Boolean
>     On Error Resume Next
>     Dim visioApp As Object
>     Set visioApp = GetObject(, VISIO_CLASS_ID)
>     VisioInstanceExist = Not visioApp Is Nothing
> End Function
> ```

Looks like a round-about way to creating an instance of Visio. It's not really a **boolean** at all. If you checked if it existed and returned a boolean to decide whether you need to create one, then it would be boolean.

Moreover, I don't see any way that the instance of Visio could exist at that point, it's the first thing you do and you've not set anything to the object.

I'd *un*refactor this

```
Private Function GetVisioInstance() As Object
    Dim visioApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set visioApp = GetObject(, VISIO_CLASS_ID)
    If visioApp Is Nothing Then
        GetVisioInstance = StartVisioInstance
    Else
        Set GetVisioInstance = visioApp()
    End If
End Function
```

**See update at bottom.**

That's really not too bad of a function and it eliminates 3 others. Your call on the error checking.

Let's look at what procedures we have left (ignore that it's in excel, that shouldn't matter)
<sub>created in [RubberDuck-VBA](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck)</sub>

[image]

Wait! There's no `.Initialize()` function. *Maybe* you can do all the creation and getting during initialization?

Otherwise -

> - Activate**Visio**Instance
> - Activate**Visio**Window
> - DetermineDesired**Visio**Window
> - Load**Visio**Drawing
> - Maximize**Visio**Window
> - Open**Visio**Drawing
> - Sync**Visio**Drawing
> - **Visio**ScreenUpdating

Now, I'll admit I'm not a **Visio** expert, but isn't this being run in Visio? Or, if it isn't, this `Class` has **Visio** in its name.

I think it's pretty clear we're dealing with Visio, don't you? That's just muddying the naming waters and really doesn't help to understand what is going on with each function. Why not just drop it?

- ActivateInstance
- ActivateWindow
- DetermineDesiredWindow
- LoadDrawing
- MaximizeWindow
- OpenDrawing
- SyncDrawing
- ScreenUpdating

Hm, that's better. I don't like that `ScreenUpdating` function, there's already `Application.ScreenUpdating`. Seems maybe that could just be a boolean *property* to `Let` and `Get`? I only actually see that property change once and then back.

> ```
> Private Sub ActivateVisioInstance(ByRef app As Object)
>     AppActivate app.window.Caption
> End Sub
> ```

Here you're using the [AppActivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/appactivate-statement?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) statement, but you've wrapped it in a `ActivateInstance` method. And you're using a [caption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/VBA/Visio-VBA/articles/window-caption-property-visio) that *is* a property of `Window` (the visio object, not your variable). But I don't see where you're using that property, I don't know what the *caption* will be. It seems like your `ActivateInstance` procedure is *less* efficient and/or clear than if you just used the `AppActivate` statement in the first place. If you're going to wrap it in something, make use of that! You aren't even taking a *caption* argument!

> ```
> SyncVisioDrawing drawing, someData
> Private Sub SyncVisioDrawing(ByRef drawing As Object, ByVal someData As String)
>     drawing.Title = someData
> End Sub
> ```

You're passing an application object into a procedure to set its title, which you're also passing to the procedure? so it's `SetDrawingTitle`? Using that procedure isn't needed. If it is, name it better, take a different argument, maybe turn it into a function to get the title, or even better - make it a property of the Class.

One thing you asked about was `OpenVisioDrawing` being confused with `LoadVisioDrawing`. Yes, that's not great naming, you're right. What is `OpenVisioDrawing` doing?

1. Checking and creating an instance of Visio
2. Loading a drawing into Visio
3. Fixing the view of Visio to what you need

That's a lot of things, and a lot of those things are broken out to other procedures already (which is great!). I'd say the sub is managing all of the visio procedures, or being the interface to visio (that's the class name right?).

---

#### Naming Variables

> ```
> Dim app As Object
> Dim drawing As Object
> Dim window As Object
> Dim visioApp As Object
> Const VISIO_CLASS_ID As String = "Visio.Application"
> Const visOpenRW = &H20
> Const visWSMaximized = &H40000000
> ```

Your first constant is UPPER_SNAKEY_CASE but the other two aren't. They aren't given *Types* either, so they are variants. What should they be? Strings I must assume. So make them strings.

Also, what are those values? `&H20` and `&H40000000` - hex notations? Of what? ASCII characters? Those constants names should at least tell me what they should be! Otherwise

> ```
> Const visOpenRW = &H20
> Set LoadVisioDrawing = app.Documents.OpenEx(filename, visOpenRW)
> ```

I have no idea what that should do. I don't know offhand what `.OpenEx` parameters are (because I'm no Visio expert). Let's [find out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/documents-openex-method-visio?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

What? Those are flags and it is an integer? And `visOpenRW` already is the constant for it. Okay, now a lot more of that makes sense, but if there's already a constant, just use it as the flag, no need to tell me there's a constant, apparently an integer, that goes as an argument (flag) into an expression. I'd know more just by

> ```
> Set LoadVisioDrawing = app.Documents.OpenEx(filename, visOpenRW)
> ```

At least I won't chase my tail around for your constant's hex notation only to find out the flag `visOpenRW` is a *built-in constant* for that expression.

The variable `app` is what I would call vague. I see you used `visioApp` once and most of your functions said "visio" - why not just use `visioApp` or `visioInstance` or something similar as your variable name? That will make sure I know we're in Visio.

You've also named a variable the same name as a [Visio Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/window-object-visio) - window. That can get confusing, but it's your call

> ```
> Sub OpenVisioDrawing(ByVal filename As String, someData As String)
> Private Function StartVisioInstance() As Object
> Sub ActivateVisioInstance(ByRef app As Object)
> Function LoadVisioDrawing(ByRef app As Object, ByVal filename As String) As Object
> Sub SyncVisioDrawing(ByRef drawing As Object, ByVal someData As String)
> Function DetermineDesiredVisioWindow(ByRef app As Object, ByRef drawing As Object) As Object
> Sub ActivateVisioWindow(ByRef window As Object)
> Sub MaximizeVisioWindow(ByRef window As Object)
> Sub VisioScreenUpdating(ByRef app As Object, ByVal allow As Boolean)
> ```

All your functions are *returning* something and all of your subs are *doing* something, great! Your variable naming is consistent, but it's not all that descriptive.

I see *a lot* of `ByRef` in there, and several that are implicitly `ByRef` because they've not been designated `ByVal`. Why are you sending everything as a reference? You're sending `Objects` `ByRef` into `Functions` that return `Objects`.

---

#### Class

I'm unclear as to why this class is existing. It doesn't seem you'll really need a factory for a bunch of Visio and I don't see any *properties* being stored in the class. I mean your class is essentially a Visio application object, if I'm reading this correctly (and I may not be).

---

#### Re: other

I ran this from Access 2016 with a sample `vxd` and the Visio window never stopped blinking in the taskbar for a new instance of Visio. If it was already open, no blinking.

The blinking starts at

> ```
> Set LoadVisioDrawing = app.Documents.OpenEx(filename, visOpenRW)
> ```

Itried moving `ActivateVisioInstance` to after `LoadVisioDrawing` but still, it blinks. I don't have a solution for that, I'm just being a negative nancy and pointing out problems :(

Stepping through the code though, still I don't understand how `VisioInstanceExist` can possibly be `True` without you calling, essentially `AttachVisioInstance`.

I was **wrong** with my example of a new version of that function. It should be

```
Private Function GetVisioInstance() As Object
    On Error GoTo NewInstance
    Set GetVisioInstance = GetObject(, VISIO_CLASS_ID)
    Exit Function
NewInstance:
    Set GetVisioInstance = CreateObject(VISIO_CLASS_ID)
End Function
```

That's my fault, sorry. The point still remains though.

**OpenVisioDrawing** should be named better, but as far as what to name it, I can only give suggestions. VisioHandler, VisioInterfacing, VisioController, something more broad.

#### Re: Class

If I move all of the class outside to the test module and just

```
Sub Test()
    OpenVisioDrawing "C:\Users\Ray\myVisioFile.vsd", "Custom drawing title"
End Sub
```

It works exactly the same as if it's in a class. Essentially your `app` is your object, not your class. And an instance of Visio is an object. What I mean is, *why* is this a class if you aren't using any *special* properties? I'm not saying it shouldn't be a class, I'm saying think about *why* it's a class and what it being a class can do for you differently than if you just stick it in a module.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim visioHandler As Object
    Set visioHandler = New VisioInterface
    With visioHandler
        .OpenVisioDrawing "C:\Users\Ray\myVisioFile.vsd", "Custom drawing title"
    End With
End Sub
```

Right, now we have an instance of the class that's an object outside of the class. What can we do with that?

Let's say in your class you put in

```
Private windowTitle As String
Public Property Get Title() As String
    Title = windowTitle
End Property
Public Property Let Title(ByVal newTitle As String)
    windowTitle = newTitle
End Property
```

Now you have something you can use *outside* of the class.

```
Sub Test()
    Const PATH As String = "C:\Users\Ray\myVisioFile.vsd"
    Dim visioHandler As Object
    Set visioHandler = New VisioInterface
    'Let .Title
    visioHandler.Title = "My Title"
    'Get .Title
    MsgBox visioHandler.Title
    'Get .Title
    visioHandler.OpenVisioDrawing PATH, visioHandler.Title
End Sub
```

So instead of just sending an entire thing into the class to do everything, you can use those methods in the standard module.

Comment: Thanks for your review and suggestion regarding `GetVisioInstance`. I will take this in account.

Beforehand: The code is not run in Visio, but Microsoft Access. Maybe that clears some of your question?

An instance of Visio can already exist by different reasons: One could be that the user startet Visio before by hand, or maybe the application where this code is running in (MS Access) could have been crashed but left Visio open with the drawing.

Regarding the too often used `Visio` in the procedure names I absolutely agree. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: `OpenVisioDrawing` does more: Avoid Windows taskbar blinking and minimize Visio screen flickering.
Do you suggest a different naming for it finally?

I agree regarding the constants casing and missing type. I need to define them because I don't reference the Visio class library and use late binding.
Their naming is taken directly from the Visio library. It could be better named, right.

You are right, regarding those `ByRef`. They should be `ByVal`. This is an old habit I'm working on. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by saying "I mean your class is essentially a Visio application object"?

I'm interested in a suggestion of how to implement the following steps in a different, maybe more clever object oriented way:
`Checking and creating an instance of Visio`, `Loading a drawing into Visio`, `Fixing the view of Visio to what you need`, `Avoid Windows taskbar blinking`, `Minimize Visio screen flickering` :-)

Comment: For `GetVisioInstance` what I mean is that you didn't try to set whatever instance may exist already to your variable, so there's no way the *boolean result* could be true. For the other comments, when I update my answer I'll ping you in the comments.

Comment: @UnhandledException added some clarification

Comment: Taskbar blinking: Did you debug the code step by step, or did you let it run at once? Latter one should work.
Activating the Visio app before loading the drawing prevents the blinking successful here on Visio 2013.
`VisioInstanceExist`:
If `Set visioApp = GetObject(, VISIO_CLASS_ID)` runs without raising an error, it means that there is a Visio process running already.
Maybe the user started Visio by hand an hour ago or whatever.
Then `Not visioApp Is Nothing` will result in `true`.
Or do we have a misunderstanding?

Comment: Thanks for your naming suggestions of `OpenVisioDrawing`. Could be to abstract. Imagine later there could be more public procedures in the class.

"Class":
"Why is this a class if you aren't using any special properties?"
I plan to do more with this class in future.
So there also will be different procedures, which will need to prevent Visio screen updating to run as smooth as possible.
Thats why I ask for how to organize those steps in the `OpenVisioDrawing` more clever in an object oriented way.
Your final suggestions could show the way. Thx.

Comment: I'm saying that VisioInstanceExists can only be true if it tries to assign a visio instance. It's just not a boolean that needs to exist. I think it's better off just with some error handling.

Comment: Ah, now I think I understand. What about renaming `VisioInstanceExists` to `VisioProcessExists`? I'm not going to check if my code already has an instance of Visio, but if there already is a Visio process running in Windows. :-)

Comment: But if one already exists you only know that by trying to assign to a variable. So just try to assign it and if it doesn't, create one. The boolean, as it is, is not giving information that is boolean.